# Finding double integral of piecewise function over a square

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> A function $f$ is defined by $$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 7e^{x^2} & y \leq x \\\\ 7e^{y^2} & y > x \end{cases}  $$ In the plane. Compute the double integral $$\int\int_Df(x,y)dA $$
>   Where $D$ is the square $[0,9] \times [0,9]$.

Im not able to integrate the function. Im also not sure what the limits should be and what "part" of the function should be where in the integral.

Comment: Can you draw-in in the square the parts where $y>x$?

Comment: @botond Yup. It forms two congruent isosceles triangles.

Comment: What can't you calculate then? The limits for those triangle areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cut $D$ into two parts $D_1=\{(x,y) \in D,\ y\leq x\}$ and $D_2=\{(x,y) \in D,\ y> x\}$.
For exemple, the integral over $D_1$ is (using Fubini's theorem)
$$\int\int_{D_1}f(x,y)dA = 7\int_0^9\int_{0}^xe^{x^2} dydx = 7\int_0^9xe^{x^2}dx. $$ You should now be able to compute it and do the same for $D_2$.

Comment: I don't get how you solved $$\int_0^{x}e^{x^2}dy$$ and got $$\frac{x}{2}e^{x^2}$$

Comment: For the first integral, you can see the integrand does not depend on $y$ so $\int_0^xe^{x^2}dy = e^{x^2}\int_0^xdy = \frac{x}{2}e^{x^2}$.

Comment: where does the $\frac12$ come from? $$ \int_0^{x}dy = x$$ doesen't it? So shouldn't the answer be $xe^{x^2}$ ?

Comment: Sorry my bad I can't compute integrals anymore

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved using cylindrical coordinates with

$$f(r,\theta) = \begin{cases} 7e^{r^2cos^2\theta} & \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4} \\\\ 7e^{r^2sin^2\theta} & \theta >\frac{\pi}{4}  \end{cases}  $$

And the integral $$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{\frac{9}{cos\theta}}7e^{r^2cos^2\theta}rdrd\theta + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{9}{sin\theta}}7e^{r^2sin^2\theta}rdrd\theta = 7(e^{81}-1)$$